# Spring kafka producer keep on waiting for one minute in some cases for producing data and failed with exception for some cases

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api, aws-msk

I have implemented Spring Kafka Template for producing event in my spring boot project.The code for producing an event is given below-

Producer Config:

```
@Beanpublic Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() throws FileNotFoundException {

Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG,kafkaProperties.getSecurity().getProtocol());
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:client.truststoreks").getAbsolutePath());
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM_CONFIG,StringUtils.EMPTY);props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,JsonSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "100");
return props;
}
```

Producer Service Code:

```
public class KafkaProducerService<V> implements KafkaProducer<V> {

@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, V> kafkaTemplate;

@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, V> transactionLogKafkaTemplate;

public KafkaProducerService(KafkaTemplate<String, V> kafkaTemplate, KafkaTemplate<String, V> transactionLogKafkaTemplate) {
    this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    this.transactionLogKafkaTemplate = transactionLogKafkaTemplate;
}

@Override
@Retryable({KafkaException.class, TimeoutException.class})
public void produce(String topic, String key, V value) {
    log.info("Calling producer service for producing event on topic "+topic);
    sendCallbackEvents(kafkaTemplate, topic, key, value);
}

private void sendCallbackEvents(KafkaTemplate<String, V> kafkaTemplate, String topic, String key, V value) {
    ProducerRecord<String, V> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord(topic, key, value);           
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, V>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, V>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, V> result) {
            log.info(String.format("Produced event to topic %s: key = %-10s value = %s", topic, key, value));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            log.error("Producing of data on topic {} is failed", topic, ex.getCause());
        }
    });
}
}
```

**P.S: We are using AWS MSK as a broker for producing an event.**

But in some cases, it's taking one minute time for producing an event and getting failed with the below error in logs-

**ERROR LogAccessor - Exception thrown when sending a message with key='xx' and payload='Event(key=value)' to topic topicName:**

Hence it's able to produce the event due to retry logic on producer service but due to that 1-minute delay, I am facing several issues.

I tried to find out the reason for the producer service delay and failure while going through the Spring Kafka dependency classes but no luck.

I am not able to find out the exact reason why the producer is getting delayed and failing in 1st attempt for some cases. Can anyone help me in identifying the reason for that and the solution to the issue?

Comment: I don't know the root cause, but the 60 seconds is likely because that's the default value of `max.block.ms` - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_max.block.ms

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks for your comment. Can you help me any direction to look for finding the root cause.

Comment: I can't sorry; I am not familiar with MSK or kafka-clients internals. I don't know if you can look at the server logs on MSK, but that is where I would start with a local broker (as well as debug logging on the client side).

Comment: I wonder if the issue might be on the connectivity to kafka or between the kafka nodes. This is just a guess as you are setting `linger.ms` which is for how long the producer will wait for more data before sending data to the broker. I also haven't used MSK, but I smell a connectivity problem. This could be explained If your app fails to connect to some of the brokers: producing to some brokers would work, but to others would fail with a time out. This could happen if there's an error in the `listeners` or `advertised.listeners properties`

Comment: @GaryRussell We tried to replicate same behavior in lower env like local dev. But not able to reproduce. It's happening in production. We have seen msk logs of those 1 min. But nothing unusual we can find out. Some rebalancing logs were there but no error

Comment: can you share the rebalancing error as well?  is there any change in consumers during this process, that is causing rebalancing? rebalancing is cpu intensive process.

Comment: @TanaySen, I know it's been 1year. Just curious, if you are able to find out the root cause?